# Compile error when using multiple generic bounds

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to define a generic method whose parameter is bound by two types, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
public static <T extends Readable, Appendable> void doSomething(T t) {
    int r = t.read(...); // compiles OK
    //
    t.append(...); // compile error
}
```

This should compile. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What is  the compiler error?

Comment: Unknown method `append()`

Answer (score 11):

The problem is that the method defines *two* parameters, one called `T` and one called `Appendable`, not one parameter with two bounds.

The comma should be an ampersand, like this:

```
public static <T extends Readable & Appendable> void doSomething(T t) {
    //
}
```